# How to receive the message from stomp websocket with spring boot on nuxt

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I used SpringBoot + Stomp + nuxt in local.
It was connected without problems and sent and received messages.
And i deployed it to Ec2 and applied https.
At this time, i am using SpringBoot + Stomp + Nginx

It can be connected on https

But doesn't receive when send a message

I think it's a failure to send messages

WebsocketConfig:

```
package com.ptw.stepjob.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer

@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class StompWebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub");
    }


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/chat")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

MessagingSendingLogic:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/message")
public void enter(TChatHistoryReqDto reqDto,
                      @Header("Authorization") Optional<String> token,
                      @Header("social") Optional<String> socialLoginCheck) {

        TChatHistoryResDto res = tChatHistoryService.createTChatHistory(reqDto, token.get(), socialLoginCheck.orElse("false"));

        sendingOperations.convertAndSend("/topic/chat/room/" + reqDto.getChatChannel(), res);
    }
```

chat.js:

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "stompjs";
import VueCookies from "vue-cookies";

class ChatClient {
  constructor() {
    this.url = "/api/ws/chat";
    this.socket = null;
    this.stompClient = null;
  }

  connectToWebSocket() {
    console.log("connectToWebSocket Start");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.socket = new SockJS(this.url);
      this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
      this.stompClient.connect(
        {},
        (frame) => resolve(),
        (error) => reject(error)
      );
    });
  }

  async initAndSubscribeToRoom(roomId, onMessageReceived) {
    if (!this.stompClient) {
      try {
        await this.connectToWebSocket();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to connect to WebSocket", error);
        throw error;
      }
    }
    this.stompClient.subscribe(`/topic/chat/room/${roomId}`, (message) => {
      const recv = JSON.parse(message.body);
      console.log("Received message", recv);
      onMessageReceived(recv);
    });
  }

  sendChatMessage(chatChannel, comment) {
    if (comment === "") {
      return;
    }

    const payload = JSON.stringify({
      chatChannel,
      chatInfo: comment,
    });

    if (!this.stompClient) {
      console.log("Not connected to WebSocket, connecting...");
      this.connectToWebSocket()
        .then(() => {
          this.stompClient.send(
            "/pub/chat/message",
            {
              Authorization: $nuxt.$user_info.getUserInfoStore().token,
              social: VueCookies.get("social_login"),
            },
            payload
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Failed to connect to WebSocket:", error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("VueCookies", VueCookies.get("social_login"));

      this.stompClient.send(
        "/pub/chat/message",
        {
          Authorization: $nuxt.$user_info.getUserInfoStore().token,
          social: VueCookies.get("social_login"),
        },
        payload
      );
    }
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.stompClient) {
      this.stompClient.disconnect(
        () => {
          console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
          this.socket = null;
          this.stompClient = null;
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error("Error disconnecting from WebSocket:", err);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}

export default ChatClient;
```

nginx.conf:

```
location /api/ws/chat/ {
                        proxy_pass http://ec2 privateIP:8080/api/v1/ws/chat/; # WebSocket Server

                        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }
```

Any hints how to solve this issue?